# flutter route with id param

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set route with id by running `stacked generate`. But it doesn't work. I was wondering how to do that.

**app.dart**

```
@StackedApp(
    routes: [
        MaterialRoute(page: SingleTopicView, path: '/committee-hub/topic/:id')
    ]
```

**SingleTopicView**

```
class SingleTopicView extends StackedView<SingleTopicViewModel> {
    const SingleTopicView({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);
    final String id;
```

Answer (score 0):

***I think for that you can use [Routemaster package](https://pub.dev/packages/routemaster) it's easier to operate dynamic routes with it***

**STEP 1. In main.dart instead of using MaterailApp() use MaterialApp.router()**

```
return MaterialApp.router(
          routeInformationParser: const RoutemasterParser(),
          routerDelegate: RoutemasterDelegate(routesBuilder: (contx) {
            return loggedInRoute;
          }),
          title: "APP",
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
```

**STEP 2. Create new file and store all your routes inside this file**

```
final loggedInRoute = RouteMap(routes: {
 "/community-details/:name": (route) => MaterialPage(
    child:
        CommunityDetailScreen(communityName: route.pathParameters['name']!),
  ),
  //other routes
});
```

**STEP 3. How to navigate using Routemaster**

```
 Routemaster.of(contx).push('/community-details/${community.name}');
```